# Doing PostGIS query with Arel.spatial

Tags: postgis, ruby

I'm trying to understand how Arel work.

How can I do this PostGIS query with Arel.spatial ?

```
SELECT
    ST_asText(ST_ClosestPoint(track.path::geometry, pta.lonlat::geometry))  AS closet_point
    FROM tracks track, pois pta
    WHERE track.id = 2
      AND pta.id = 2
```

pta is a point like `t.geography "lonlat", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"st_point", :geographic=>true}`
track.path is a linestring like `t.geometry "path", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"line_string"}`